# Merging two data.frames using ancillary data.frame dplyr R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I would like to merge two data.frames using third data.frame `matches` which provides the key of how the previous two should be merged (`id` and `number` are the matching keys. `Class` should always match and it serves as an additional check). 
`df2` should be merged to `df1` replacing columns with the same names and inserting variables from `df2` into respective rows into `df1` (in this example those rows would be score but in my real examples it is about 20+ columns that should be replaced among 30 or so (remaining 10 would stay the same). I hope this is clear and thanks a lot in advance for help how to do it efficiently.
It needs to be `left_join` as I would like to retain all records in `df1`. `dplyr` is a preference!

```
df1 <- data.frame(1:10,
                  c("a","b","a","b","c","c","b","a","b","c"),
                  seq(20,38,2),
                  dnorm(10,5,2),
                  rnorm(10,78,5))
colnames(df1) <- c("id","class","score","misc","hc")
df2 <- data.frame(11:19,
                  c("g","d","a","e","c","d","f","a","b"),
                  seq(40,48,1),
                  dnorm(9,6,1),
                  rnorm(9,45,3))
colnames(df2) <- c("number","class","score","other","md")

matches <- data.frame(c("b","a","c","a"),
                      c(4,1,5,8),
                      c(19,18,15,13))
colnames(matches) <- c("class","id","number")

library(dplyr)
```

Expected output:

```
id class          misc       hc number   score       other       md
 1     a    0.00876415 70.85210     18      47 0.004431848 40.99189
 2     b    0.00876415 81.27802     22      22          NA       NA
 3     a    0.00876415 69.19300     24      24          NA       NA
 4     b    0.00876415 75.86247     19      48 0.004431848 44.78242
 5     c    0.00876415 69.18268     15      44 0.004431848 42.70708
 6     c    0.00876415 80.49475     30      30          NA       NA
 7     b    0.00876415 76.52195     32      32          NA       NA
 8     a    0.00876415 73.52712     13      42 0.004431848 45.69842
 9     b    0.00876415 81.50631     36      36          NA       NA
10     c    0.00876415 80.55145     38      38          NA       NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>% left_join(matches,by=c('id','class'),suffix=c('.df1','.df2')) %>%
        left_join(df2,by=c('class','number'),suffix=c('.df1','.df2')) %>% 
        mutate(score=if_else(!is.na(score.df2),score.df2,score.df1)) %>% 
        select(-score.df1,score.df2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed it to:
`df1 %>% left_join(matches,by=c('id','class')) %>% left_join(df2,by=c('class','number'))` as I would like to retain all records in `df1`. The problem is that column score is not getting replaced in score.x. I would like to have no score.x and score.y just one score with replaced values from `df2` or left as they were in df1 if there was no reference to it in `matches`

Comment: @MIH Sorry I didn't get you. Is this what you are looking for. If not please provide your expected output.

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what I need! Now, the only last issue is that I have about 30 variables among 40 to replace(just as score was merged). Any idea how to make it more generic to apply to a lot of columns? Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 1):

Just do two merges like that:

```
tmp = merge(df1, matches, all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE)
res = merge(tmp, df2, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
res
```

Comment: Thanks @jakob-r . And how to do it to retain all values in `df1` ?